# Borrar un objeto seleccionado en pantalla del array

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un Listview y un menu contextual creo que se llama, de manera que si doy un click largo en una de las filas de listview me sale el menu. en menu tiene 2 opciones una es borrar. el problema es que no se como saber la posicion seguro para mandar al remove. Os dejo lo que he hecho y ya me decis como lo veis. Mi idea es obtener la posicion con un getSelectItemposicion del listview y pasar dicha posicion al remove de arraylist

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList datos = new ArrayList();
        private ListView listCuadros;
        private AdaptadorCuadros adaptador;
        private Context contexto;
        private View tv1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            contexto = this;
            datos.add(new Cuadros("La Mona Lisa","Leonardo da Vinci","Renacentista","$713 millones","1503"));
            datos.add(new Cuadros("El grito","Munch","Expresionismo","$119.9 millones","1893"));
            datos.add(new Cuadros("La persistencia de la memoria","Dalí ","Surrealismo","$400","1931"));
            datos.add(new Cuadros("El nacimiento de Venus","Sandro Botticelli","Gotico","Desconocido","1482"));
            datos.add(new Cuadros("Guernica","Pablo Picasso","Cubismo","€300 millones","1937"));
            datos.add(new Cuadros("Los jugadores de cartas","Paul Cézanne","Posimpresionismo","€191 millones","1890"));
            adaptador = new AdaptadorCuadros(this, datos);
            listCuadros = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            listCuadros.setAdapter(adaptador);
            registerForContextMenu(listCuadros);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mimenu, menu);
        }

        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.mi1:
                    editar();
                    return true;
                case R.id.mi2:
                   borrar();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        private void editar(){

        }
       private void borrar() {
        String mensaje = "Va a borrar uno de los cuadros, esta seguro?";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
        builder.setTitle("Confirmacion");
        builder.setMessage(mensaje);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.i("Dialogos", "Confirmacion Cancelada.");
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.i("Dialogos", "Confirmacion Aceptada.");
                datos.remove(listCuadros.getSelectedItemPosition());
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase adaptadora

```
public class AdaptadorCuadros extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<Cuadros> datos;

AdaptadorCuadros(Activity context, ArrayList datos) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, datos);
    this.context = context;
    this.datos = datos;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (item == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        holder.titulo = item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        holder.autor = item.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
        holder.precio = item.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
        holder.estilo = item.findViewById(R.id.tvEstilo);
        holder.fecha = item.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
        item.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
    }
    holder.titulo.setText(datos.get(position).getTitulo());
    holder.autor.setText(datos.get(position).getAutor());
    holder.precio.setText(datos.get(position).getAutor());
    holder.estilo.setText(datos.get(position).getEstilo());
    holder.fecha.setText(datos.get(position).getFecha());
    return (item);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView autor;
    TextView precio;
    TextView estilo;
    TextView fecha;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la clase AdaptadorCuadros?

Comment: Listo ya lo tienes puesto en lapregunta

Comment: ¿Y dónde enlazas el menú contextual con el evento de pulsación sobre la lista? Se supone que si implementas un listener sobre la lista, en los parámetros del listener tienes el índice del elemento de tu lista sobre el que se ha pulsado.

Comment: No se, yo le dejo pulsado cualquiera de las lineas del listview con ese codigo y me salta el menu como se enlanza ni idea

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con "menú"? ¿Por qué no usas un `AlertDialog`? Sería más fácil aunque la definición es la misma para eliminar

Answer (score 0):

Bien, suponiendo que tienes una clase y demás vamos a lo directo, ¿Cómo eliminar un objeto desde un `ListView`?

En tu clase debes tener los objetos:

```
ArrayList<Camiones> arrayCamiones; //un array de la clase
adaptadorCamiones adt; //el adaptador del ListView
DBGeneral conn; //yo uso una db en SQLite
```

Vamos con el `ListView`:

```
lvCam=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCamion);
        arrayCamiones = new ArrayList<Camiones>();
        conn = new DBGeneral(getApplicationContext());
        arrayCamiones=conn.llenar_Cam();//este es un método para llenar el array 
        adt =new adaptadorCamiones(ListaCamion.this, arrayCamiones);
        lvCam.setAdapter(adt);
```

Y acá viene lo importante:

```
lvCam.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final  int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaCamion.this)//ListaCamion es la clase donde está
                        .setTitle("¡Alerta!")
                        .setMessage("¿Qué desea hacer?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Eliminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                DBGeneral bd = new DBGeneral(getApplicationContext());//llamo a la bd
                                bd.borrarCam(arrayCamiones.get(position).getIdCamion()) //la conecto con el método de eliminar por medio del id;
                                onResume();
                            }
                        })//OMITE LO SIGUIENTE
                        .setNegativeButton("Modificar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UpdateCamiones.class);
                                intent.putExtra("cho", arrayCamiones.get(position));
                                startActivity(intent);
                                buscCam.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                alertbox.show();
            }
        });
```

En tu caso en vez de esta línea:

```
bd.borrarCam(arrayCamiones.get(position).getIdCamion())
```

Deberías usar algo como esto:

```
TuObjeto.remove(position);
```

Comment: El problema es que el borarr no puede ir hay porque va dentro de un menu conextual que salta al dar clic largo en el listview. Si tengo una clase cuadros